# Build ServiceStack 4 locally

Tags: .net, servicestack, strongname

ServiceStack recently changed to one of their assemblies being signed.  What is the least friction way to build the project locally so I can make some changes and submit a contribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack's v4 solution has been updated to have all projects now reference the pre-built `/lib/ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll` so you should be able to build from the `master` branch now.